# Subtracting two vector<point2f> directly

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have to subtract two vectors of type Point2f (both are of same size). I know it can be done by extracting the values at each index and then subtracting them in a loop but is there a direct method to it? Something like

```
Vector<Point2f> A[3];
A[2] = A[1] - A[0];
```

Comment: If you include a bit about Point2f, any c++ coder can help you probably...

Comment: Its a basic structure used in the OpenCV library
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point

Comment: Thanks, i found it already. It's just that this one is your only (and not neccessary for the core question) dependency on opencv. It's best to reduce any dependencies in your questions, so more people might try their hands on helping you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just for sports ;)

```
std::vector<Point2f> A,B;
A.push_back(Point2f(1,2));
A.push_back(Point2f(3,4));
A.push_back(Point2f(5,6));
B.push_back(Point2f(5,2));
B.push_back(Point2f(4,4));
B.push_back(Point2f(3,6));

// Mat C; subtract(A,B,C);
Mat C = Mat(A) - Mat(B);
cout<< A << endl << B << endl <<C<<endl;



[1, 2;  3, 4;  5, 6]
[5, 2;  4, 4;  3, 6]
[-4, 0;  -1, 0;  2, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation link that you provided, subtraction of two points is supported. So the following should work:

```
std::transform (A[1].begin(), A[1].end(), A[0].begin(), A[2].begin(), std::minus<Point2f>());
```

Note that this assumes that A[2] is big enough to store the result.

Alternative, you could write your own overloaded operator-() for vector subtraction:

```
const vector<Point2f> operator-(const vector<Point2f>& lhs, const vector<Point2f>& rhs)
{ ... }
```

You would need to optimize the above function to avoid a copy of the vector when the function returns. This does not preclude the need to write the looping code that you want to avoid. But it will give you a cleaner syntax for vector subtractions.